# Snakemake output with expand and different number of parameters

Tags: directory, wildcard, snakemake

I've got this rule in snakemake:

```
    output:
        RESULTS + folderdestination + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/predictions_{e}_{n}_{h}_run{r}.csv"
        dir=directory(RESULTS + folderdestination + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/")
```

I need to pass to another rule, just the folder:

```
    dir=directory(RESULTS + folderdestination + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/")
```

However the number of wildcards used are different and snakemake won't allow me to use the second statement in the same rule as it raises

```
Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule analysis contain the same wildcards. This is crucial though, in order to avoid that two or more jobs write to the same file.
```

Is there any way to "extract" in a snakemake way the folder, without the needs of re-write the code of the program?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with a param: `params: dir=RESULTS + folderdestination + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/"`

Comment: Yes, however if I do so, it start the elaboration of the folder before it is filled with the files from the "output" of the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the people that might be facing the same problem. After some test I made it by creating a dummy "middleware" rule. So the first rule is:

```
 output:
        RESULTS + folderdestination + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/predictions_{e}_{n}_{h}_run{r}.csv"
```

which is called by the expand on `feats`, `edges`, `labels`, `e`, `n`, `h`, `r`.

Then below I created this dummy rule with a selective expand that takes the files just created and returns just the folder:

```
rule dummy:
    input:
        expand(RESULTS + folderdt + "/{{feats}}/{{edges}}/{{labels}}/predictions_{e}_{n}_{h}_run{r}.csv",  e=e, n=n, h=h, r=r),
    output:
        RESULTS + folderdt + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/",
```

Lastly, I got my rule that takes as input the output folder created in the dummy rule:

```
rule summary:
    input:
        folder=RESULTS + folderdt +"/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/"
    output:
        file=RESULTS + folderdt +"/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/summary.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need the intermediate rule or the dir as an output.  Directory labels are important for rules that output unknown numbers of files, like a scatter operation.  In your case, snakemake will still make all the nested directories prior to starting the job.  Assuming you have a recent version of snakemake, expand can also take a named argument called 'allow_missing' so you don't have to mask wildcards.  Overall I am thinking:

```py
base_dir = RESULTS + folderdestination + "/{feats}/{edges}/{labels}/"
prediction = base_dir + "predictions_{e}_{n}_{h}_run{r}.csv"
summary = base_dir + "summary.csv"

rule make_prediction:
    output: prediction

rule summary:
    input:
        predictions=expand(prediction, e=e, n=n, h=h, r=r, allow_missing=True)
    params:
        base_dir
    output:
        file=summary
    # do things with {params.folder}, can ignore predictions.
```

With e, n, h, r = range(2), `snakemake -nq feat1/edge1/label1/summary.csv` gives:

```sh
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        16      make_prediction
        1       summary
        18
```

Because params just contains the folder path with wildcards, the wildcards will be replaced.  Using touch for outputs and echoing params.folder in the summary rule gives:

```sh
feat1/edge1/label1/
```

Comment: You're right. At the end of the day I decided to use as the "input" of the rule "summary" all the predicted files and the folder as parameter. The former are not actually used, while it is passed to the shell command just the parameters.folder

Comment: That is a feature of snakemake that isn't readily apparent.  The input and output directives are really just for snakemake to know what's going on, they don't have anything to do with the command!  These "implicit" inputs and outputs occasionally throw me off if something requires an index file or produces additional output not present in the command invocation.  Glad you got it working.